# Borders don't show up in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's the landing page I'm doing now http://prototype.uedpro.ru 
It's in cyrillic, don't worry.

In the gallery, there are labels with photo names which are made up with `height: 0` and diagonal borders which show up in every other browser now, but not in FF. I tried almost everything and I still can't figure out what's wrong. Any tips?

Whole gallery's css:

```
.thumbwrap {
  width: 472px;
  height: 314px;
  margin: 6.5px auto; }

.thumbwrap img {
 width: 100%; }

.trap {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 0;
   width: 485px;
   border-top: 32px solid #3d4344;
   -moz-border-top: 32px solid #3d4344;
   -o-border-top: 32px solid #3d4344;
  border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -moz-border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -o-border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
   border-right: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -moz-border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -o-border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    position: relative;
    -moz-transform: scale(.9999);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.42));
   filter: url(#drop-shadow);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=0,     OffY=1,Color='#000')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=1,Color='#000')";
     behavior: url('../stylesheets/PIE.htc');}

#trap1 {
  height: 0;
  width: 245px;
    border-top: 32px solid #3d4344;
    -moz-border-top: 32px solid #3d4344;
    -o-border-top: 32px solid #3d4344;
    border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -moz-border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -o-border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
   border-right: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -moz-border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -o-border-left: 32px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    position: relative;
   -moz-transform: scale(.9999);
  behavior: url('../stylesheets/PIE.htc');
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 }

#trap1 span {
 left: 50px;
 top: -25px;
 font-size: 15px; }

#trap2 span {
 top: -26px;
 right: 0;
 font-size: 12px; }

.thumbpad span {
 position: absolute;
 top: -29px;
 right: -5px;
 color: #b4dbe1;
 font-size: 10px; }

.activepad {
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  z-index: 9999 !important; }

.activetrap {
    width: 245px !important;
    border-top: 32px solid #FFFFFF !important;
    -moz-border-top: 32px solid #FFFFFF !important;
    -o-border-top: 32px solid #FFFFFF !important;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* behavior: url('../stylesheets/PIE.htc'); */}

  .activespan {
   color: #000000 !important;
    left: 55px;
}
```

Js:

```
var zindex = 7;
var thumbs = $('.thumbpad');
var i = 8;
var margin = 1;
$('.thumbpad').each(function(){
    $(this).css('z-index',i);
    i-=1;
       });

for (i = 5; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
     $(thumbs[i]).css('width',$(thumbs[i]).width() + 2).css('top',-margin);
}


$('.thumbpad').hover(function(){
   if (!$(this).hasClass('activepad')) {
       var prev = $(this).prevAll();
       var next = $(this).nextAll();
       var index = $(this).index()+1;
       var i =index;
       var j = index;
       $(prev).each(function(){
        $(this).css('z-index',i-1);
         $(this).find('.trap').css('width','245px');
         $(this).find('span').css('left','0');
       });
   _.each($(prev).toArray().reverse(),function(){
           $(this).css('z-index',i-1);

       });
       removeWhite($('#first_thumb'));
       addWhite($(this));
   }
},function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('activepad')) {
        var prev = $(this).prevAll();
        var i = 8;
        $('.thumbpad').each(function(){
            $(this).find('.trap').removeAttr('style');
            $(this).find('span').removeAttr('style').css('right','-5px');
            $(this).css('z-index',i);

            i-=1;
        });
       removeWhite($(this));
        addWhite($('#first_thumb'));

    }
});

function addWhite (pad) {
    $(pad).addClass('activepad');
    $(pad).find('.trap').addClass('activetrap');
    $(pad).find('span').addClass('activespan');
}

function removeWhite (pad) {
    $(pad).removeClass('activepad');
    $(pad).find('.trap').removeClass('activetrap');
    $(pad).find('span').removeClass('activespan');
}
```

Comment: Please put relevant code **here**.

Comment: @JeevanJose Added current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `.trap` CSS rule this is breaking Firefox

```
filter: url(#drop-shadow);
```

Remove it or comment it out and they will show up.

Also I don't think you can pass an ID based selector to a url() in CSS though I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes it is, if you bothered to read the question you would see the issue is with firefox and not chrome :)

Comment: i already bothered to  knew that but i want to know why that rule is breaking in firefox and not breaking in chrome

Comment: I have no idea why one browser doesn't break and the other does to be honest but I know that's the rule breaking firefox

Comment: Thanks, that worked indeed but how do I make a dropshadow work? I followed http://demosthenes.info/blog/600/Creating-a-True-CrossBrowser-Drop-Shadow-Effect-With-CSS3-&-SVG this article and passed the selector like it said there.

Comment: that what i was asking